# How to connect an existing virtual netwrok to DevTest lab using ARM or Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-cli, azure-virtual-network, azure-devtest-labs

I have a resource group that contains separately created DevTest lab and Virtual Network (VNet) using Bicep.

I can manually by using the Azure portal attach the VNet to the Devtest lab by:

1. Go to Devtest lab
2. Select "Configuration and policies"
3. From the External resources menu, select "Virtual networks"
4. Click "Add"
5. Select the VNet

**Is it possible to automate this process using Azure CLI? or any other alternative?**

As I am adopting Azure DevOps pipelines to run (Bicep code) and adjust (Azure CLI) the resources automatically.

I am using ARM/Bicep template (`Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-02-01`) for VNET, and  (`Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs@2018-09-15`) for DevTest lab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating Vnet and Devtest lab separately then you can use the below [Azure Quickstart Template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devtestlab/tree/master/samples/DevTestLabs/QuickStartTemplates/301-dtl-create-lab-with-existing-vnet) from Github for creating a Devtestlab with existing vnet :

**JSON ARM:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "newLabName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The name of the new lab instance to be created."
        }
      },
      "newLabVirtualNetworkName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The name of the new lab virtual network instance to be created with the new lab instance being created."
        }
      },
      "existingVirtualNetworkId": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The resource ID pointing to an existing (compute) virtual network to be referenced by the new lab virtual network instance being created."
        }
      },
      "existingSubnetName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "default",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The name of an existing (compute) subnet instance to be configured for Lab VM creation."
        }
      }
    },
    "variables": {
      "existingSubnetId": "[concat(parameters('existingVirtualNetworkId'), '/subnets/', parameters('existingSubnetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "apiVersion": "2018-10-15-preview",
        "type": "Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs",
        "name": "[parameters('newLabName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "resources": [
          {
            "apiVersion": "2018-10-15-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('newLabVirtualNetworkName')]",
            "type": "virtualNetworks",
            "dependsOn": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs', parameters('newLabName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "description": "Existing Compute virtual network associated as part of the lab creation process.",
              "externalProviderResourceId": "[parameters('existingVirtualNetworkId')]",
              "subnetOverrides": [
                {
                  "name": "[parameters('existingSubnetName')]",
                  "resourceId": "[variables('existingSubnetId')]",
                  "useInVmCreationPermission": "Allow",
                  "usePublicIpAddressPermission": "Allow"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "labId": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs', parameters('newLabName'))]"
      }
    }
  }
```

**Outputs:** I tested it on my environment and the results are as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Unfortuantely, there are no commands to connect vnet and [Devtestlabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-overview) using [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/lab?view=azure-cli-latest) or [Azure-Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.devtestlabs/?view=azps-6.4.0#devtest-labs).

**BICEP ARM:**

```
@description('The name of the new lab instance to be created.')
param newLabName string

@description('The name of the new lab virtual network instance to be created with the new lab instance being created.')
param newLabVirtualNetworkName string

@description('The resource ID pointing to an existing (compute) virtual network to be referenced by the new lab virtual network instance being created.')
param existingVirtualNetworkId string

@description('The name of an existing (compute) subnet instance to be configured for Lab VM creation.')
param existingSubnetName string = 'default'

var existingSubnetId = '${existingVirtualNetworkId}/subnets/${existingSubnetName}'

resource newLabName_resource 'Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs@2018-10-15-preview' = {
  name: newLabName
  location: resourceGroup().location
}

resource newLabName_newLabVirtualNetworkName 'Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/virtualNetworks@2018-10-15-preview' = {
  parent: newLabName_resource
  name: newLabVirtualNetworkName
  properties: {
    description: 'Existing Compute virtual network associated as part of the lab creation process.'
    externalProviderResourceId: existingVirtualNetworkId
    subnetOverrides: [
      {
        name: existingSubnetName
        resourceId: existingSubnetId
        useInVmCreationPermission: 'Allow'
        usePublicIpAddressPermission: 'Allow'
      }
    ]
  }
}

output labId string = newLabName_resource.id
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot see that this template is included in Bicep. However, I see that I can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devtestlab/2018-09-15/labs/virtualnetworks?tabs=bicep

Comment: hello @A7med, i have provided the above for only json arm template , yes we can use bicep as well . let me convert the above json to bicep and add it to the answer.

Comment: This is a correct way of solving the problem, thanks. Here is the same solution suggested in MS community https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/566490/how-to-connect-an-existing-virtual-netwrok-to-devt.html